# How to detect the origin of a webpage's GET requests programmatically? (C#)

Tags: c#, get, webclient, redirect

In short, I need to detect a webpage's GET requests programmatically.

The long story is that my company is currently trying to write a small installer for a piece of proprietary software that installs another piece of software.

To get this other piece of software, I realize it's as simple as calling the download link through C#'s lovely `WebClient` class (`Dir` is just the Temp directory in AppData/Local):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("[download link]", Dir.FullName + "\\setup.exe");
}
```

However, the page which the installer comes from does is not a direct download page. The actual download link is subject to change (our company's specific installer might be hosted on a different download server another time around).

To get around this, I realized that I can just monitor the GET requests the page makes and dynamically grab the URL from there.

So, I know I'm going to do, but I was just wondering, is there was a built-in part of the language that allows you to see what requests a page has made? Or do I have to write this functionality myself, and what would be a good starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd do it like this.  First download the HTML contents of the download page (the page that contains the link to download the file).  Then scrape the HTML to find the download link URL.  And finally, download the file from the scraped address.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    // Get the website HTML.
    string html = client.DownloadString("http://[website that contains the download link]");

    // Scrape the HTML to find the download URL (see below).

    // Download the desired file.
    client.DownloadFile(downloadLink, Dir.FullName + "\\setup.exe");
}
```

For scraping the download URL from the website I'd recommend using the HTML Agility Pack.  See [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/9b86d4/getting-started-with-html-agility-pack/) for getting started with it.

Comment: I'd thought about doing it this way, but as performance is one of my top priorities, I'd rather not scrape the entire response...I may have to resort to that though. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to write your own "mediahandler", which returns a HttpResponseMessage.

e.g. with webapi2

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("route")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetFile([FromUri] string path)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
    string disposition = "attachment";
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(disposition) { FileName = fileName + Path.GetExtension(absolutePath) };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Path.GetExtension(path)));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I'm writing a client. I'm not on the server-side. I want the GET requests that the server has made once the page has loaded. This answer is not helpful.

Comment: yepp I completely misunderstood